# Angular SSR How use canActive Auth guard

Tags: angular

Angular SSR not support  can activate auth guard in any routing .show ho to support can activate auth guard in angular SSR.can activate auth guard use user authentication in any rouing module .

Answer (score -1):

Angular SSR canActive Authguard not support in renderning time so this problem solution find isPlatformBrowser this find Returns whether a platform id represents a browser platform then solve Authguard problem solution

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.